# QGIS - Bad Allocation error message on zoom or atlas generation

Tags: qgis, error

I've seen a few topics on the 'Bad Allocation' error message, but nothing that's help solve my problem yet.   I have a virtual layer returning records from multiple tables, but I can't identify any of the records in the canvas.  It appears to be tied to the geometry - if it's on 'Autodetect', simply nothing happens when I try to zoom to a selected a feature; if I've specified the geometry (in this case, LineString), I'll get the bad allocation error.  Same thing happens in composer if my atlas is based on the virtual layer - either nothing, or bad allocation.

Comment: Which qgis version?

Comment: I'm using the latest - 2.18.16